# How to store enum as string instead of int in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using `grpc`+`golang`+`mongodb`, and I have the following `proto` file.

```
enum InventoryType {
    LARGE = 0;
    SMALL = 1;
}
```

my go code:

```
import (
    "context"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"

    "inventory-service/pb"
)

func (i *Inventory) CreateInventory(ctx context.Context, req *pb.CreateInventoryRequest) (*pb.CreateInventoryResponse, error) {
    inventory := req.GetInventory()

    data := pb.Inventory{
        Inventory: inventory.GetInventory(),
    }

    mctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    client, _ := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))

    collection := client.Database("test_db").Collection("test_collection")
    collection.InsertOne(mctx, data)

    return &pb.CreateInventoryResponse{}, nil
}
```

and when I save the enum to mongodb using golang, it saves the int value 0, 1 instead of 'LARGE', 'SMALL', any ideas on how I can save string instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protobuf is for *communication*, not for database modeling. You shouldn't use protobuf generated files to save in your database.

Instead create a separate type that models the document you want to store in the database, in which you may store the string representation of your enum, and that will get stored in the database.

For example:

```
type MyData {
    Inventory string `bson:"inventory"`
}
```

And using it:

```
data := MyData{
    Inventory: inventory.GetInventory().String(),
}
```

Comment: What is the standard way to do this, because I do see google official doc using generated code for modelling, https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial.

Comment: Also, if i create separate models, ex, I have 2 micro services, `User` and `Inventory`, and if `Inventory` depends on `User`, does that mean I need to create my own User model twice in both `Inventory` and `User`?

Comment: Yes, it's used for modeling, but not database objects but data for communication.